# Does an r value of 0.60 mean that an increase in one variable is 60% likely to mean an increase in the other variable?

Tags: correlation

If one has an r value of 0.60, can one state that an increase in one variable is 60% likely to mean an increase in the other variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, your interpretation is incorrect.

Common interpretations of a correlation between X and Y equal to .60 include:

1. X explains the following proportion of variance in Y: $0.60^2=.36$ . I.e., 36% of variance.
2. A value one standard deviation larger on X is associated with a value .60 of a standard deviation larger on Y.

Both these statements are bidirectional. I.e., you could switch the words X and Y in the above two statements and the statements would still be true.